# what is isogeny category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, nt.number-theory

I see this term in a paper. There is no abelian variety whatsoever involved. There is an original category which consists of $Z_p$ modules with some properties, lets denote as $\mathfrak{C}$, then the author says that $\mathfrak{C}\otimes Q_p$ is its "isogeny category". What is this supposed to mean? Is it some "change of base"? Or are there general notion of "isogeny category"?
Thank you.

Comment: Assuming that in the original category the Hom-sets have the structure of $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules, my guess is that the isogeny category has the same objects, but the Hom-sets are formally tensored from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Q}_p$.  

Comment: Anyway, if you tell us which paper it is, we can probably be more helpful.

Comment: it's in Kisin's paper "Crystalline representations and F-crystals". the very above of Page 19。 Thank you!

Comment: oh, sorry, the original category is not modules over $Z_p$..I'll correct it in the post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Pete Clark intimates in his comment: If you have a category $\mathfrak C$ in which the Hom sets are $R$-modules, and composition is $R$-bilinear, and if $S$ is an
$R$-algebra, then you can form the category $\mathfrak C \otimes_R S$ in which you tensor all Hom sets by $S$ over $R$.

If $\mathfrak C$ is the category of abelian varieties, then taking $R = \mathbb Z$ and
$S = \mathbb Q$, this construction leads to the category of abelian varieties "up to isogeny", or "isogeny category" of abelian varieties, hence the name in general.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Generally, if $\mathfrak{C}$ is a $\mathcal{V}$-enriched category and $F : \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{W}$, then you can get a $\mathcal{W}$-category by applying $F$ to each hom-object of $\mathfrak{C}$; in this generality it's usually denoted $F_*(\mathfrak{C})$, but in particular cases it's often written just $F(\mathfrak{C})$, as here with $F = (-\otimes_R S)$.